# Why left join gives different results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Whats wrong with this query, When I run query on http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
it will show results what I want, but when running on PHP page it will give different results.

[image]

but when I Fetch results on PHP page it will give empty records also

[image]

how can I get records without those empty SubCategoryID and SubCategory Name

Here is PHP code

```
    <table id="subCat1Table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sub Category ID</th>
      <th>Sub Category Name</th>
      <th>Root Category ID</th>
      <th>Root Category Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <!-- <tfoot>
  <tr>
    <th>Sub Category ID</th>
    <th>Sub Category Name</th>
    <th>Root Category ID</th>
    <th>Root Category Name</th>
  </tr>
  </tfoot> -->
  <tbody>
    <?php
    $query1 = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM sub_category1 LEFT JOIN main_category ON sub_category1.main_category_id = main_category.category_id ');

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
    // Result Assigning to Array
    $rows[] = $row;
    }
    // traversing Array
    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($rows);
    echo("</pre>");
    foreach($rows as $row):
    // Getting Values
    $subCategory1ID = stripslashes($row['sub_category1_id']);
    $subCategory1Name = stripslashes($row['sub_category1_name']);
    $rootCategoryID = stripslashes($row['category_id']);
    $rootCategoryName = stripslashes($row['category_name']);
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo "$subCategory1ID"; ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo "$subCategory1Name"; ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo "$rootCategoryID"; ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo "$rootCategoryName"; ?> </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    endforeach; //End ForEach loop
    ?>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you sure the queries are the same? Are they run on the same database?

Comment: Yes I am using same query on same database

Comment: Post a dataset and add code highlighting.

Comment: `SELECT *` is generally a bad coding idea. And why the `LEFT JOIN` in the first place when it is not wanted?

Comment: I think, you are generating the grid incorrect. Would you post the entire php code ?

Comment: Change the `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN` and then we can go home.

Comment: no change with changing from LEFT JOIN to JOIN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LEFT JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table (table1), and the matched records from the right table (table2). The result is NULL from the right side, if there is no match.

**You should use inner join to fetch match record only**

Answer (score 0):

The problem here occurred due to assigning values to array in while loop

```
<?php
    $query1 = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM sub_category1 LEFT JOIN main_category ON sub_category1.main_category_id = main_category.category_id ');

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
    // Result Assigning to Array
    $rows[] = $row;
    }
    // traversing Array
    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($rows);
    echo("</pre>");
    foreach($rows as $row):
    // Getting Values
    $subCategory1ID = stripslashes($row['sub_category1_id']);
    $subCategory1Name = stripslashes($row['sub_category1_name']);
    $rootCategoryID = stripslashes($row['category_id']);
    $rootCategoryName = stripslashes($row['category_name']);
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo "$subCategory1ID"; ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo "$subCategory1Name"; ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo "$rootCategoryID"; ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo "$rootCategoryName"; ?> </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    endforeach; //End ForEach loop
    ?>
```

Now without assigning to array

```
<?php
     $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM sub_category1 INNER JOIN main_category ON sub_category1.main_category_id = main_category.category_id");

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)):
    // Getting Values
    $subCategory1ID = stripslashes($row['sub_category1_id']);
     $subCategory1Name = stripslashes($row['sub_category1_name']);
     $mainCatID= stripslashes($row['main_category_id']);
     $rootCategoryID = stripslashes($row['category_id']);
     $rootCategoryName = stripslashes($row['category_name']);
     ?>
     <tr>
       <td><?php echo "$subCategory1ID"; ?> </td>
                                <td><?php echo "$subCategory1Name"; ?> </td>
       <td><?php echo "$mainCatID"; ?> </td>
       <td><?php echo "$rootCategoryID"; ?> </td>
                                <td><?php echo "$rootCategoryName"; ?> </td>
     </tr>
    <?php
     endwhile; //End ForEach loop
?>
```